# Bootstrap dropdown tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown to switch between panes for the selected item in the dropdown.
Normally it would switch panes when I press on the item from the dropdown but since the new bootstrap version (4.0.0-beta.2) it doesn't respond anymore and it leaves me with a `tab.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined` error.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hsoby0g/)

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="adventure" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="adventure-tab">
   <div class="card" style="">
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="large-clipper" aria-labelledby="large-clipper-tab">
            <div class="card-header">
               <div class="dropdown btn-group float-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Variations
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" role="tablist" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                     <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="large-clipper-tab" href="#large-clipper" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="large-clipper" aria-selected="false">Large Clipper</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="festive-large-clipper-tab" href="#festive-large-clipper" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="festive-large-clipper" aria-selected="false">Festive Large Clipper</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <img src="http://eversong.ivyro.net/SHIP/00000024.png" height="50" width="50">
               <h4 style="display:inline-block">Large Clipper</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <h6 class="text-muted">
                  Just a big and fast clipper.
               </h6>
               <p class=" p-y-1">
                  <span style="font-style:italic">Level requirements: </span>
                  <span>Adventure: 30 </span>
                  <span>Trade: 56 </span>
                  <span>Maritime: 75</span>
               </p>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block my-1" href="">Selling: <span>5</span> </a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block my-1" href="">Buying: <span>10</span> </a></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade" id="festive-large-clipper"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="large-clipper-tab">
            <div class="card-header">
               <div class="btn-group float-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="variationsDropdown" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown"> Variations </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="variationsDropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#large-clipper" data-toggle="tab">Large Clipper</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#festive-large-clipper" data-toggle="tab">Festive Large Clipper</a>                                             
                  </div>
               </div>
               <img src="http://eversong.ivyro.net/SHIP/00000024.png" height="50" width="50">
               <h4 style="display:inline-block">Festive Large Clipper</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <h6 class="text-muted">
                  A large clipper but with fancy plating.
               </h6>
               <p class=" p-y-1">
                  <span style="font-style:italic">Level requirements: </span>
                  <span>Adventure: 30 </span>
                  <span>Trade: 56 </span>
                  <span>Maritime: 75</span>
               </p>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block my-1" href="">Selling: <span>5</span> </a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block my-1" href="">Buying: <span>10</span> </a></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Required files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide run able code, read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added the required files, should run just fine like this. The JSFiddle works for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with tabs in v4 beta 2, this will be fixed in beta 3, see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23087